Remove section numbering from some chapters
My thesis has several chapters, and a few of them have sections and subsections. However, for the chapters that do not have sections, the theorem counter continues to label them "X.0.1, X.0.2" etc... how do I get rid of these "middle zeros"? I would like to keep the rest of the numbering the same, for instance,
Chapter 1
Section
Definition 1.1.1
Theorem 1.1.2
etc.
--
Chapter 2
Definition 2.1
Theorem 2.2
etc.

Welcome! Can you provide some code people can compile to reproduce the problem? This should be a complete but minimal document with just enough preamble and content to demonstrate the issue. Without knowing the code which typesets your theorems, we can't tell you how to modify it.

There are two options (you probably are in favor of the second one):
A: keeping the 3 digits for numbering but setting 0 to 1:
Due to the missing subsection the LaTeX counter subsection is not increased by 1. But you can do this manually: e.g., after the \section{...} command just add
\addtocounter{subsection}{1}

and the respective counter's value was increase as it would have been if you would have had a subsection.
(The counters also exist for section, subsubsection etc)
B: Switching from 3 digits to 2 digits
This is a bit unusual but can be achieved as follows:
\documentclass[english,11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\numberwithin{theorem}{subsection}


\begin{document}
    \section{One}
    \subsection{Sub-One}
    \begin{theorem}
        content
    \end{theorem}
    
    \section{Two}
    %\addtocounter{subsection}{1}
    \numberwithin{theorem}{section}

    
    \begin{theorem}
        content
    \end{theorem}
    
\end{document}


This then gives the following document:

Note, that you might have to switch back to the  "3 digit section numbering" by \numberwithin{theorem}{subsection} (adjust chapter/section/subsection to your case, of course).
